# Differential Modulation in a SIMO system

Tags: decision, single-input-multiple-output

In a SIMO system with a DBPSK modulation, the reception is given by

$$\sum_{p=1}^{N}y_p [n]=z[n]$$

with $y_p[n]=r_p^{\ast}[n-1]r_p[n],\ r_p[n]=x[n]h_p[n]+w_p[n]$, where $N$ is the number of antennas, $h_p$ the channel impulse response for the $p^e$ antenna and $w_p[n]$ the noise for the $p^e$ antenna.

After we have the decision process. With a DBPSK modulation we have $2$ symbols $\{d_1,d_2\}=\{-1,1\}$.  Consequently, the decision process is given by

$$\arg\min_i\left\lvert z[n]-d_i\right\rvert.$$

And if $i=1$, then $z[n]=d_1$.

Is it equivalent to do the sum of SIMO after the decision process and if yes why?
More precisely this process: $\arg\min_i\left\lvert y_p[n]-d_i\right\rvert$ and if $i=1$ then $y_p[n]=d_1$. And after, $z[n]=\sum_{p=1}^Ny_p[n]$ with $z[n]$ equal to $d_1$ or $d_2$ depending on the majority. That is to say, if there are more $d_1$ than $d_2$ then $z[n]=d_1$.